# Why address information are not properly stored with gethostbyname and inet_pton functions?

Tags: c, sockets

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr,sizeof addr);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    struct hostent *server = gethostbyname("192.168.1.139");
    printf("%s %d\n",server->h_addr,inet_pton(AF_INET,server->h_addr,&addr.sin_addr.s_addr));
    int res = connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof addr);
    printf("%d\n",res); 

    while (1){
        char buf[100] = "";
        fgets(buf,100,stdin);
        send(sockfd,buf,sizeof buf,0);
    }
}
```

If I execute this code, I always get:

```
$ ./client 
��� 0
-1
```

So:

1. Why I get these random chars? Why I don't see the IP string of h_addr?
2. Why the return of inet_pton is 0? It should be 1, 0 is for unsuccessfull, so why it fails?
3. Obviously, the connect fails.

Also, if instead of using inet_pton, I use this line:

```
bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&addr.sin_addr.s_addr,h_length);
```

it works. BUT WHY it works this way and in the other way it doesn't??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My English is not very good, so please understand.

See [gethostbyname() man page](http://man.he.net/?topic=gethostbyname%20&section=all).

> The gethostbyname() function returns a structure of type hostent for the given host name. Here name is either a hostname or an IPv4 address in standard dot notation (as for inet_addr(3)). If name is an IPv4 address, no lookup is performed and gethostbyname() simply copies name into the h_name field and its **struct in_addr equivalent into the h_addr_list[0] field** of the returned hostent structure.

h_addr_list[0] is struct in_addr and h_addr_list[0] is **h_addr**, See below.

**struct hostent**

```
struct  hostent {
 char *  h_name;     
 char ** h_aliases; 
 int     h_addrtype;  
 int     h_length;    
 char ** h_addr_list;
};

#define h_addr  h_addr_list[0]
```

**struct in_addr**

```
struct in_addr {
  uint32_t s_addr;
}
```

So, if you want to see the IP string of h_addr, see the code below.

```
printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)server->h_addr));
```

And you can use it by assigning the value of s_addr as `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(unit32_t *)server->haddr;`

Or you can make it simpler using `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.139");`